# variable no of arguments for class template's member function

Tags: c++, templates

I am just learning about templates and was trying to write a simple template class for vectors like

```
template <unsigned N>
struct vec {
    std::array<float, N> m_buffer;

    float& operator[](unsigned index) { return m_buffer[index]; }

    vec(float value) {  std::fill(m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.end(), value); }

    vec(float(&value)[N]) { std::copy(std::begin(value), std::end(value), std::begin(m_buffer)); }

    vec(float* value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            m_buffer[i] = value[i];
    }

    float getmag() {
        float ret=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            ret += m_buffer[N] * m_buffer[N];
        return sqrt(ret);
    }
};

int main() {    

    vec<3> a({ 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f });

    return 0;
}
```

now I want to make a contructor that will take N number of floats and assign them to the array m_buffer but did not find any ways.
This could be done for certain values of N by specializing the template class but how will one do for any number of N?

Comment: Are you looking for [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template)s maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use variadic template:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct vec {
    std::array<float, N> m_buffer;

    template <typename ... Ts>
    vec(Ts... args) : m_buffer{{args...}} {}

// ...
};
```

SFINAE might be added to check arity and to restrict to float convertible parameters.

Alternative which might be appropriate is usage of index_sequence:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using always_t = T;

template <typename Sequence> struct vec_seq;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct vec_seq<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof...(Is);
    std::array<float, N> m_buffer;

    vec_seq(always<float, Iss... args) : m_buffer{{args...}} {}

// ...
};

template <std::size_t N>
using vec = vec_seq<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```